# grant access to new user phpmyadmin locally

Tags: php, mysql

Im working locally with XAMPP, and I'm attempting to connect to the database with a new user.

The username has all permissions granted both globally and specific to that table (altough theres no need for both), but when I try and connect using the code below I get an error, I have no issues connecting with 'root'.

I've double checked passwords.

Am I missing something else?

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'myshop'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\db_connect.php on line 8
Couldnt Connect to DB
```

```
<?php 

$db_name = 'myshop';
$username = 'myshop';
$password = 'myshop';
$host_name = 'localhost';

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name,$username,$password,$db_name);
if ($connect) { echo "<br />Success"; } else { echo "<br />Couldnt connect to DB"; } 
?>
```

Comment: Did you do a `flush privileges` after creating the user? Can you see the record (with correct data) in the mysql.user table?

Comment: no, I was unaware of that tbh, Ill look it up now (unless its a very quick piece of code you may know? :) )

Comment: I tried `flush privileges;` but that didnt work

Comment: Is the user `myshop@localhost` listed in phpMyAdmin’s user list at `pMA-URL/server_privileges.php` ?

Comment: I had a look for that file and found phpmyadmin/server_privileges.php but no there is no sign of mmyshop@localhost there

Comment: Using phpMyAdmin, are you able to log in with this myshop user?

Comment: no, I cant actually, I changed/confirmed the password one more time,and ran `flush privileges;` one more time and still nothing